# How to handle two whereRaw condition with column aliases in Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel

> I am using below queries

```php
if($a != "") {
    $getData = DB::table('students')
    ->whereRaw("code = :code AND class != :class AND gender = :gender", ["code" => 1, "class" => "General", "gender" => "m"])->get(['code as c', 'class as c','students.*']);
}

if($b != '') {
    $queryData=$getData->whereRaw(" ST_Distancesphere(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longt, :latt), 4326)) < :b", ["longt" => $longt, "latt" => $latt, "b" => $b])->get();
} 

return $queryData;
```

> when $a !='' this condition is true in that case query run perfectly
>   but when second case is true $b!='' in that case give me an error
>   Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::whereRaw does not exist.

Comment: because you are return the collection in case 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using query builder, and you used `->get()` in first condition, this will return the collection result. It has no `whereRaw` method.

You need to use `select()` instead of `get()`

```php
if($a != "") {
    $queryData = DB::table('students')
               ->whereRaw("code = :code AND class != :class AND gender = :gender", ["code" => 1, "class" => "General", "gender" => "m"])
               ->select(['code as c', 'class as c','students.*']);
}

if($b != '') {
    $queryData = $queryData->whereRaw(" ST_Distancesphere(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longt, :latt), 4326)) < :b", ["longt" => $longt, "latt" => $latt, "b" => $b]);
} 
return $queryData->get();
```

Comment: let me know in that case should i need to remove the get() method in second query

Comment: @sumitkundan It seems if `$a == ""` and `$b != ''`, you will get error, because you have no `$getData`. So if you have `$getData` before `$a == ''`, you need to remove `get()` in second condition, and add `get()` before it return.So that the query will get the datas to collection.

Comment: in my case $a!=''" and $b!='' in that case its give me an error Call to a member function get() on string

Comment: it means you call `get()` on `string`.do u remove the `get()` in second condition. do u use `$queryData->get()` at last?

Comment: in first case am using like $queryData->get() and in second $getData->whereRaw(" ST_Distancesphere(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longt, :latt), 4326)) < :b", ["longt" => $longt, "latt" => $latt, "b" => $b])->get()

Comment: @sumitkundan I have updated. Use `$queryData` instead of `$getData`, and remove all the `get()`, add `get()` at last.